# Transfer PreInstalled Games from a bundle WiiU

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4, splatoon, nintendo-network-id

I want to buy a Splatoon/SSB4 WiiU Bundle, but I already own another WiiU with an NNID Account (also linked to my 3DS).

Can I download the pre-installed SSB4 and Splatoon to the Other WiiU? And if it is possible to do that, can I use my existing account or do I have to create another one?

Comment: I don't think you can bind the second WiiU with the same NNID. Anyway, usually only one game is pre-installed, for the other one you'll find a download code. So for the latter you shouldn't have any problem. 

(Mario Kart 8 + Splatoon bundle worked this way, only the first one was pre-installed.)

Comment: Do the bundles include download codes or are they preinstalled? If it's the former, you could just do a system transfer.

Comment: I bought the Splatoon bundle a few months ago and it was just a download code. You should simple be able to claim that on your other WiiU.

Answer (score 1):

According to Nintendo's [Wii U to Wii U transfer FAQ](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8983):

> Will I need to redownload content on the target Wii U after the transfer has been completed?
>
> During the system transfer process, any content that was downloaded on the source Wii U will be added to Download Manager on the target Wii U. This means it will be queued to download automatically after the transfer has been completed. The maximum number of queued downloads is 64. Any excess downloads will need to be downloaded by adding them from the Nintendo eShop.

So, by using the Wii U to Wii U Transfer Tool, you should be able to redownload the pre-installed game. For safety's sake, I would recommend doing what you can to ensure both systems are linked to your Nintendo Network ID first, which may include calling Nintendo support; also, since the bundled copy of Splatoon is provided via download code, just download it after the transfer is done.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, as long as they have the same NNID you can find it in downloaded content.